# Book not updated: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064

Tags: php, sql, pdo

Book not updated: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'Practical Guide to Linux Commands, Editors, and Shell Programming, bookYear=2010' at line 1

Can anyone help me with where I have gone wrong?

Here is my php:

```
    <?php
    // Retrieve variables
    $bookISBN = filter_has_var(INPUT_GET, 'bookISBN') ? $_GET['bookISBN'] : 
    null;
    $catDesc = filter_has_var(INPUT_GET, 'catDesc') ? $_GET['catDesc'] : 
    null;
    $bookYear = filter_has_var(INPUT_GET, 'bookYear') ? $_GET['bookYear'] : 
    null;
    $bookPrice = filter_has_var(INPUT_GET, 'bookPrice') ? $_GET['bookPrice'] 
    : null;
    $bookTitle = filter_has_var(INPUT_GET, 'bookTitle') ? $_GET['bookTitle'] 
    : null;

    $errors = false;

    if (empty($bookTitle)) {
        echo "<p>Book title cannot be empty</p>\n";
        $errors = true;
     }
     if (empty($catDesc)) {
         echo "<p>Category cannot be empty</p>\n";
         $errors = true;
     }
     if (empty($bookYear)) {
         echo "<p>Book Year cannot be empty</p>\n";
         $errors = true;
     }
     if (empty($bookPrice)) {
         echo "<p>Book price cannot be empty.</p>\n";
         $errors = true;
     }

     if ($errors === true) {
         echo "<p>Please try <a href='chooseMovieList2.php'>again</a>.                  </p>\n";
     }

     else {
         try {
             require_once("functions.php");
             $dbConn = getConnection();

             $updateSQL = "UPDATE nbc_books SET catID=$catDesc,          
    bookTitle=$bookTitle, bookYear=$bookYear, bookPrice=$bookPrice WHERE 
      bookISBN = $bookISBN";
    $dbConn->exec($updateSQL);
     echo "<p>Book updated</p>\n";
         } catch (Exception $e) {
             echo "<p>Book not updated: " . $e->getMessage() . "</p>\n";
         }
     }
     ?>
```

Comment: String values like your book title need to be quoted in SQL; or better yet, learn to use parameterised queries with bind variables